# How do I execute a .deb file

Tags: execute-command

I downloaded `deb-creator-i386` and it seemed to install. It is supposed to be a GUI for compiling and packaging. After install it says in order to run or execute the program or app, I have to do that with a command in terminal. Tried use `./`.  Did not work. I am using Lubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this utility, but if it installed correctly, it should have added itself to your commands. You should be able to type something like "deb-creator" in the terminal to launch it. Maybe try typing "deb" then hit tab once or twice to see if it auto completes the command?

Comment: *"Tried use "./". Did not work."* what **exactly** did you type? what **exactly** happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) For your question [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line/769542#769542) is the best one because it also installs the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `dpkg -i deb-creator-i386.deb` directly is not good idea because of dependencies.

Better ways are:

```
sudo apt-get install ./deb-creator-i386.deb
```

and GDebI:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi gdebi-common
sudo gdebi-gtk ./deb-creator-i386.deb # GUI
```

or

```
sudo gdebi ./deb-creator-i386.deb # from terminal
```

After installation you can find its executable with

```
dpkg -L deb-creator-i386 | grep bin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the deb file with apt in a terminal. Open a terminal an navigate to the foilder where the downloaded deb file was saved. Then install the deb file with the command:

`sudo apt-get install ./deb-creator-i386.deb`

Comment: Don't understand why this was voted down, my proposed solution works fine  is also recommended on the [German Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Paketinstallation_DEB/#apt) for installing deb files.

Answer (score 0):

To install a .deb file, open a terminal and type

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

drag the deb into the terminal and click enter

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this in the terminal,

`sudo dpkg -i deb-creator-i386.deb`

Then hit Enter.

Comment: This is the perfect method to install deb files through terminal. Otherwise double click to open with software center and install